# Linux Bash Script find and join

Tags: bash, file, join, grep

Below are my example files.

Using AccountInfo(Account) to search the sub-folder existing on FolderStatus(Sub-folder).

#### `AccountInfo`

```
#server,Account,status,homefolder
vmftp01,admin01,enable,/home/admin01
vmftp01,admin02,enable,/home/admin02
vmftp01,admin03,enable,/home/admin03
```

#### `FolderStatus`

```
#account,sub-folder
admin01,/sftp/inbox
admin02,/ftp/inbox
admin02,/sftp/inbox
admin02,/as2/inbox
admin03,/ftp/inbox
admin03,/sftp/inbox
```

Desired Output:

```
/home/admin01/sftp/inbox
/home/admin02/ftp/inbox
/home/admin02/sftp/inbox
/home/admin02/as2/inbox
/home/admin03/ftp/inbox
/home/admin03/sftp/inbox
```

I tried:

```
join -t 1.2,2.2 file1 file2
```

with error:

```
join: file2:4: is not sorted: admin02,/as2/inbox
```

Comment: What is your question? What did your research show re the error message & how it applies to your case? [mre] [ask] [help] Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your FolderStatus file is indeed not sorted, but that's only a problem because your join command line doesn't seem to be correct.

try

```
join -t , -1 2 -o 1.4,2.2 AccountInfo FolderStatus
```

With AccountInfo = f2 and FolderStatus = f1, it worked for me this way (up to a comma that can be easily eliminated):

```
ronald@oncilla:~/tmp$ join -t , -1 2 -o 1.4,2.2 f2 f1
/home/admin01,/sftp/inbox
/home/admin02,/ftp/inbox
/home/admin02,/sftp/inbox
/home/admin02,/as2/inbox
/home/admin03,/ftp/inbox
/home/admin03,/sftp/inbox
```

The "-t ," option specifies the field separator.
The "-1 2" option specifies that the key in file 1 is the second column. And the "-o" flag specifies the output format

Comment: Let me try it using my huge data. Thanks